How to intercept Ctrl-d?
I have the following Greasemonkey script:
(function() {
    'use strict';

    document.addEventListener('keyup', (ev) => {
        if (ev.ctrlKey && (ev.key == 'e' || ev.key == 'd')) {
            GM_log(ev);
            ev.preventDefault();
        }
    }, false);
})();

I tried it in Tampermonkey in Firefox. It works for Ctrl-e but does not work for Ctrl-d. How to make it working for Ctrl-d?

I did a search on ctrl-d and got this: "Ctrl + D is the short key used to add a bookmark of the page currently opened in a Chrome browser. it is used to add the current site to a bookmark or favorite. All major Internet browsers like Chrome, Edge, Firefox, Opera create a new bookmark for the current page while pressing Ctrl+D." So if you are using one of these web browsers, Ctrl-D will never be passed along to your page - you cannot intercept it.

Using keyup doesn't work for me in Brave if the key combination is a keyboard shortcut for the browser itself, but using keydown (and preventing the default) does allow the script to catch it.
